# Compile Error when Adding Custom Cordova Plugin To Ionic Project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a plugin that I'm building that I will use to connect an ionic app to a bluetooth Zebra printer. I have built out the plugin.xml, .h, and .m files correctly (from what I can tell, First plugin). When I add the plugin from the git repo, everything adds OK, but when I run

```
ionic build ios
```

it returns the following error.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/Mobile\ Concierge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mobile\ Concierge.build/Objects-normal/i386/ZebraPrinter.o Mobile\ Concierge/Plugins/com.bgoforth.cordova.plugin.zebra-printer/ZebraPrinter.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

and then further down it has this error

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/maxorpharmacy/Documents/Development_Projects/MobileConciergeApp/11212016/MobileConciergeApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Mobile Concierge.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,Mobile Concierge,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/maxorpharmacy/Documents/Development_Projects/MobileConciergeApp/11212016/MobileConciergeApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/maxorpharmacy/Documents/Development_Projects/MobileConciergeApp/11212016/MobileConciergeApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I am at a loss as I've never developed and deployed a cordova plugin before, but I followed the documentation, but could (and probably did) have missed something.

Has anyone ever experienced this? My repo is at https://github.com/billycomic/CordovaZebraPrinter

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: cordova version?? and platform versions

Comment: Platforms: android 5.1.1, ios 4.0.1, windows 4.3.2 Cordova: 6.0.0 Thanks!

Comment: update your plugin.xml                                                                   <engines>
   <engine name="cordova" version=">=6.0.0"/>
    </engines>